# One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. Navigating from Table View to Web View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, webview

I'm trying to make an app that enables the user to choose a website from the table to go to that website. I have a UITableViewController that is embedded in Navigation Controller and a segue from table cell to web view. But every time I click on a website from the table view, it leads me to a blank page for a second and then to my website. I want to be able to go directly to the web page without a blank view in between. How could I go about this? Thank you!

TableViewController code:

```
import UIKit

class WebTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var websites = [Website]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        websites = WebsiteList.getAllWebsites()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return websites.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let website = websites[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = website.name
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Website") as? WebsiteViewController{
            vc.selectedWebName = websites[indexPath.row].name
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

WebViewController code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebsiteViewController: UIViewController {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    var selectedWebName = String()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = selectedWebName

        webView = WKWebView()
        view = webView
        if let url = URL(string: "https://" + selectedWebName){
            webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        }
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    }
}
```

Website Structure:

```
import Foundation

struct Website{
    var name: String
}

struct WebsiteList{
    static func getAllWebsites() -> [Website]{
        return [
            Website(name: "youtube.com"),
            Website(name: "apple.com"),
            Website(name: "hackingwithswift.com")
        ]
    }
}
```

[Web view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66XRM.png)

[A blank page between table view and web view after clicking on the back arrow from the previous view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHgba.png)

Comment: isn't it because the page is still loading/initializing your webView thats why you have a "blank screen"? just my guess

Answer (score 0):

You should import WebKit if you are writing this for iOS 8 or later for your WebViewController.

Then your UIWebView becomes a WKWebView and 
    webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))

becomes: webView.load((URLRequest(url: url))

Also this may be my preference but you don't need to make getAllWebsites a static function. If you instantiate WebSiteList in your view controller you can call that function and any others that you may need later.

Comment: You should up vote and or mark it as the answer if it answered your question. Glad to help.

Comment: The problem hasn't been solved that's why I didn't. I added images as links below the code to further clarify the issues.